# React State Change Not Causing component to Re-Render

Tags: javascript, pagination, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I'm still new to ReactJS, and I've run into a bit of a snag. I'm trying to implement pagination in a React component; however, even though my pagination function is being called successfully the state change is not causing the component to Render again.

I'm using one function to get the initial data (getMainFeed) and then a second one (getMoreItems) for the pagination. The second function is called by my 'handleScroll' function. Interestingly enough, when I replace the 'getMoreItems' function with the 'getMainFeed' function, the state change causes the component to render the additional data perfectly. Unfortunately I need to hit these two separate APIs and I don't think it would be in good form to combine the two calls into one function. So is there a way that I can get 'getMoreItems' to render the new items to the screen?

```
var data = [];


var GridView = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    return {
      data: [],
      page: 0,      //for pagination
      loadingFlag: false,
    };
    },

  getMainFeed: function() {

    var nextPage = 1; //increase the page count
    ajax_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8200/api/content/main/";
    ajax_type = "GET";
    ajax_data = {
       'BatchCount': "20"
    };

    $.ajax({
       url: ajax_url,
       type: ajax_type,
       contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       data: ajax_data,

       dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data) {
      this.setState({
        data: data,
        loadingFlag:false,
        page: 2

      });
      //loading("off");
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)

    });

   }, //end function
   getMoreItems: function() {
    var nextPage = this.state.page+1; //increase the page count
    ajax_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8200/api/content/page/1/";
    ajax_type = "GET";
    ajax_data = {
       'BatchCount': "20"
    };

    $.ajax({
       url: ajax_url,
       type: ajax_type,
       contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       data: ajax_data,

       dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data) {
      this.setState({
        data: data,
        loadingFlag:false,
          page: nextPage
      });

    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
    });

 }, //end function
  componentDidMount: function() {
    //loading("on");
    this.getMainFeed();
  },
  handleScroll:function(e){
    //this function will be triggered if user scrolls
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var inHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var scrollT = $(window).scrollTop();
    var totalScrolled = scrollT+inHeight;
    if(totalScrolled+1200>windowHeight){  //user reached at bottom
      if(!this.state.loadingFlag){  //to avoid multiple request 
          this.setState({
            loadingFlag:true,  
          });
          //loading("on");
          this.getMoreItems();
      }
    }
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function() {

    $('#grid-container').imagesLoaded( function() {
      MasonryInit();
    }); 
  },
  render: function() {
      return (
        <div id="feed-container-inner">
          <GridMain data={this.state.data} />
        </div>

      );
    }
  });
```

Comment: is `success` being executed in `getMoreItems`?

Comment: Yep, success always is called. I wasn't setting the data properly.

Answer (score 0):

When the state change it will re-render. Also you saw that it was working with your getmainfeed function.

So I think that your getmoreitems function just do not success. Have you verified that this call succeed ?

Comment: Nope, the function always succeeded. Turns out I had to concatenate the data

Answer (score 0):

The problems turns out to be that I wasn't concatenating the data to the end of the existing data like so `data: this.state.data.concat(data),`.

This surprises me, because I would have expected the getMoreItems function to simply replace the existing data.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. I think that the render function was triggered and your view rerender, however the format was bad and your view cound'lt display it. even if rerendered.

Comment: Also you shouldn't change state via 'this.state'.
You should always change via setState.
From react.js implementation of setState:


  Sets a subset of the state. Always use this to mutate
  state. You should treat `this.state` as immutable.

Comment: JavaScripts Array.concat returns a new array without modifying the existing one, so use like this is fine.  See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)